# Rails. Capybara fill_in finds text inputs but doesn't fill_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

So I have this feature spec in my Rails app

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'As a signed in user' do
  let(:user) {create(:user)}
  let(:article) { create(:article)}
  before {login_as(user, :scope => :user )}

  scenario 'I can edit article with valid attributes' do
    visit edit_article_path(article)
    puts current_path
    fill_in 'article_name', with: 'Valid name'
    fill_in 'article_content', with: 'Valid content'
    # save_and_open_page
    click_button 'Update Article'
    expect(article.name).to eq 'Valid name'
  end
end
```

and `fill_in` doesn't actually fill the input fields with `Valid name` and `Valid content`. I debug it by saving and opening page and the values remain the same so I guess it's not problem with my Rails app but rather something with Capybara. In other future spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'As a signed in user' do
  let(:user) {create(:user)}
  let(:article) { build(:article)}
  before {login_as(user, :scope => :user )}

  scenario 'I can create article with valid attributes' do
    visit '/articles/new'
    fill_in 'Name', with: article.name
    fill_in 'article_content', with: article.content
    expect {click_button 'Create Article'}.to change {Article.count}.by(1)
  end
end
```

everything works as expected. The error I am getting is:

```
Failures:

  1) As a signed in user I can edit article with valid attributes
     Failure/Error: expect(article.name).to eq 'Valid name'

       expected: "Valid name"
            got: "Name1"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/features/articles/article_update_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What can be the reason for it and how to make a spec pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're using the rack-test driver since your test isn't tagged as js: true.  Assuming that is true, your issue is that `article` is already in memory, and is not reloaded from the DB before checking for the name change.  Updating your test to the following will force a reload and then your test should pass

```
expect(article.reload.name).to eq 'Valid name'
```

If you're not using the rack-test driver then click_button will be asynchronous and you'll have other issues since you're not checking for changes in the browser before checking for database object changes.